# x86-64 "linear address" for PEBS from Linux userspace?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64

Is it possible to use the Haswell CPU feature PEBS (Precise Event Based Sampling) directly from a Linux userspace process instead of using a kernel interface?

I have succeeded in accessing performance counters from userspace using the RDPMC instruction and only using the kernel for WRMSR. This makes me very happy.

Now I want to also access PEBS. To do this I need to use the MSR IA32_DS_AREA to supply a "debug store" memory area. However, I am not sure how to allocate this memory and what address I need to use. I can allocate 2MB of contiguous physical memory (Linux HugeTLB with mlock()). I can also resolve the physical address of this memory (via procfs). However, I am not sure whether either the virtual or physical address is suitable as the "linear address" to supply for the MSR. (My concern is that the address may have to be in the kernel's virtual address space that I don't have access to.)

How can I prepare suitable memory for IA32_DS_AREA and logging PEBS events without writing a custom kernel module?

Comment: I'd expect linear address means virtual address in your process's address space.  It's *possible* but unlikely it needs physical addresses, and extremely unlikely that kernel virtual addresses would have anything to do with this.  I think [Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/) has some code for using perf counters within your program, to turn sampling on/off to get counts only for what you want to profile.

Comment: Interesting. On the one hand it sounds very convenient for the CPU to resolve the virtual address based on the page table in effect. On the other hand this can be fatal: WRMSR only works on ring0 and I am accessing it via a kernel module (/dev/cpu/<n>/msr). So the WRMSR instruction will presumably execute in the kernel context and I don't see any clever code in msr.c to force the userspace memory map to be used.

If this were the case then perhaps the physical address could rescue me if I could depend on that being mapped in a known place in the kernel?

Comment: Here is an example that I need to study:
https://github.com/pyrovski/powertools/blob/master/msr_pebs.c

Comment: Just copying from the github thread: 
The PEBS code isn't mine; please contact Barry Rountree. He has done some work with PEBS. The MSR writes in our library are handled through /dev/cpu/*/msr via the msr kernel module.

Comment: Hmm, I misread your question initially.  It's possible kernel virtual addresses are relevant.  I didn't notice the bit where you did have to use WRMSR in kernel-mode.  I've only used perf counters through the `perf` command (which isn't setuid root), and previously `oprofile`.  Anyway, Linux does have a perf-counter subsystem already.  **Have you looked into just using the kernel API that `perf` uses?**  I think there's a library for writing programs that profile themselves (or other processes) in custom ways.  I'm pretty sure some of the counters in `perf` are PEBS.

Comment: My goal is to avoid using the kernel API. I prefer to interact with hardware directly. I am not sure if it is possible or not in this instances though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by using the perf infrastructure (you avoid using RDPMC/WRMSR). You can find several examples in [this Github repo](https://github.com/deater/perf_event_tests) and more specifically tests within the `tests/record_sample` directory have multiple examples using the PEBS infrastructure through perf.

Comment: that's very useful. thank you for posting.